# Traversing a vector of list

Tags: c++, list, vector, graph, traversal

```
/* struct represents edges for a directed graph */
struct Edge {
public:
    Edge(int aTo = 0, int aCost = 0) {
        to = aTo;
        cost = aCost;
    }
    int to;
    int cost;
};

/* Graph object is used store graph using adjacency list 
method and implements Dijkstra's Algorithm to produce 
the shortest path from vertex s to all other vertices */

class Graph {
public:
    vector<int> Dijkstra(int src) const {
        // My method (stated below) goes here
    }

private:
    ...
    vector<list<Edge> > adjacencyList;
}
```

My question then is how do I traverse a list of edges in order to insert into a heap?

For example ( Note: (#) represents index of vector array), let's say we have 3 vertices and adjacency List representation is the following:

```
(0) 0 --> 1 --> 2 --> null
(1) 1 --> 2 --> null
(2) 2 --> null
```

I want the first vertex, vertex 0, and want to access the vertices 1 & 2 to retrieve the cost to get to each to put on another data structure (i.e. heap).

My approach was the following:

```
for (auto it = adjacencyList.at(0).begin(); it != 
     adjancencyList.at(0).end(); it++) {
    // use it pointer to access each vertex's cost
}
```

this produces error:

```
Value of type 'std::__1::__list_const_iterator<Edge, void *>' 
is not contextually convertible to 'bool'
```

Let me know if more clarification needed.

Comment: Going to need that more clarification, I'm afraid. The for loop is not going to produce the error message given without help. Consider using `for (auto & edge: adjacencyList.at(0))` instead.

Comment: Ok, no syntax error, i.e. seems to work. Thank you! I will try and provide more clarity. @user4581301

Comment: No syntax error does not necessarily mean "seems to work". It could work, but all the absence of syntax errors tells you is the syntax is correct. If you want to see just how wrong correct syntax can get, watch a political debate.

Comment: @user4581301 Very true :)